# html5 canvas drawing: fast motion with mouse cancels line before it hits the edge of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The app works fine so far except if the line is drawn really fast and leaves the edge of the canvas, the line is then not drawn to the edge of the canvas. There is a part missing from it.

I'm trying to fix the issue with:

`canvasVar.addEventListener ('mouseout', clearPathIfMouseCursorLeavesCanvasFunc);`

and

```
 function clearPathIfMouseCursorLeavesCanvasFunc(e){
 contextVar.beginPath(); // clears the path so buttonpresses dont connect the line
 mouseButtonHeld = false;
```

I've tried some things like adding a `settimeout();` but nothing worked so far. I don't know what causes this and I've been searching if someone else had this problem and a fix for it, but every canvas drawing app I've come across has the same issues.

It's very important that the line is drawn to the edge and that the users mouse motion is recognized, not just a line to the last coordinates where the mouse left the canvas.

It's been days now that I'm stuck with this problem. Help is really appreciated!

Whole Code:

```js
// Varibale declaration
var canvasVar = document.getElementById('canvasHtmlElement');
var contextVar = canvasVar.getContext('2d');
var pointRadiusVar = 0.5;
var mouseButtonHeld = false;
var pointsArrPosition = 0;

//Arrays
var pointsArr = [];

// Varibale declration end

//canvas setup
canvasVar.width = window.innerWidth;
canvasVar.height = window.innerHeight;

//canvas setup end


//resize fix
window.onresize = function() {
    var tempImageVar = contextVar.getImageData(0, 0, canvasVar.width, canvasVar.height);
    canvasVar.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvasVar.height = window.innerHeight;
    contextVar.putImageData(tempImageVar, 0, 0);
  }
  //resize fix end

//functions

// Objects

function pointObject() {

  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.fill = '#444444';

}

function addFilledCircleFunc(x, y) {
  //alert('works1');
  var filledCircle = new pointObject;
  filledCircle.x = x;
  filledCircle.y = y;
  pointsArr.push(filledCircle);

  contextVar.lineWidth = 10; //pointRadiusVar * 2; // Line Width
  contextVar.lineTo(pointsArr[pointsArrPosition].x, pointsArr[pointsArrPosition].y);
  contextVar.stroke();
  //contextVar.beginPath();

  contextVar.fillRect(filledCircle.x, filledCircle.y, 1, 1);
  //contextVar.arc(filledCircle.x, filledCircle.y, pointRadiusVar, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  //contextVar.fill();
  //contextVar.lineWidth = 0.5;
  //contextVar.stroke();
  //contextVar.beginPath();


  pointsArrPosition++;
  //contextVar.moveTo(pointsArr[pointsArrPosition].x, pointsArr[pointsArrPosition].y);


  //alert(pointsArr[0].x);



}

//Objects end

// create circle on mouse clicked point while mousebutton is held
var addPointToCanvasVar = function(e) {
  if (mouseButtonHeld) {
    //alert('addpointfunc');
    addFilledCircleFunc(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }
};

// MAKE SURE that lines work when drawn over the edge of the canvas

function clearPathIfMouseCursorLeavesCanvasFunc(e) {
  contextVar.beginPath(); // clears the path so buttonpresses dont connect the line
  mouseButtonHeld = false;
}

// end


// mouse Up/Down functions
var mouseDownVar = function(e) {
  //alert("mouseDown");
  addPointToCanvasVar(e); // add point on first click, not just when mousebutton is held
  mouseButtonHeld = true;

}

var mouseUpVar = function() {
  //alert("mouseUp");
  mouseButtonHeld = false;
  contextVar.beginPath(); // clears the path so buttonpresses dont connect the line
}

// mouse Up/Down Switch end


//functions end


//listeners

canvasVar.addEventListener('mousemove', addPointToCanvasVar);
canvasVar.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpVar);
canvasVar.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownVar);
canvasVar.addEventListener('mouseout', clearPathIfMouseCursorLeavesCanvasFunc);

//listeners end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Confident Drawing</title>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0">
  <canvas id="canvasHtmlElement" style="display: block;">
    Your Browser does not support Canvas! Please update to a newer version.
  </canvas>

  <script src="main_0.06.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

If you don't get what I mean: Run the snippet and draw a line as fast as you can while exiting the canvas.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't get what is your problem, or what you are trying to achieve....  ok I got it, missed the "really fast" part

Comment: What exactly you want?...I am not clear with your problem :(

Comment: What you can try to work around this problem is to listen for the mousemove / mouseup events on the body.

Comment: thx Ill try that. I did delete the canvasVar. before the addEventListener but it didn't work.

Comment: You want to draw line at corners of canvas wherever mousepressed+mouseout(out of canvas) event occurs?

Comment: No I want the lines to follow the mouse cursor to the edge of the canvas even when the mouse is used really fast. Currently If you make a fast stroke with the mouse and the cursor leaves the canvas the line is incomplete.

Comment: I've found a drawing app that seems to have fixed this problem by increasing the area that can be drawn on. Maybe by using that too I can fix it. My problem with that fix is that the line has to stop at the edge of the shown canvas. Maybe I can use that fix and just not show and delete what has been drawn outside. With that fix I will probably get problems with scaling later, so I'll only use it if I can't find anything else.

Comment: Using 2 Canvases didn't help at all, at least not the way I used them.

Comment: This is what you wanted, right? https://jsfiddle.net/62eyLuac/

Comment: Yes but it only works for me in jsfiddle. When I use it on my PC it works exactly like my original. At first I thought it might be because the cursor exits from the browser to the windows shell. But its the same for jsfiddle and there it works fine. Really strange.

Comment: I've tried my code in jsfiddle and there I get the same problem. So your code seems to fix the issue at least partially.

Comment: I just realized that your fix is exactly what I can't use. A line to the last point of the canvases edge. If you draw a curve that fix will destroy the curve by going straight to that point.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the line ends prematurely near the edge when you quickly draw a line across the edge is because the last `mousemove` event fired when the mouse was still in the canvas and just short of the edge, and the very next `mousemove` event fired after your mouse left the canvas.  To fix that problem, simply draw your line from the last recorded mouse position in the canvas to the one outside of the canvas as soon as the `mouseout` event fires.

You can add a new global variable `mousePosition` and initialize it to `{x:0,y:0}`.  Every time `mousemove` fires (whenever you call `addPointToCanvasVar`), record the `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` to your `mousePosition`.  Then when `mouseout` fires (whenever you call `clearPathIfMouseCursorLeavesCanvasFunc`), draw the rest of the line from `mousePosition` to the current `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` position.  This will complete the line to the end of the canvas edge.